# External Angle Bisectors meeting in collinear points.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> If $H$ is any point within $\Delta ABC$, prove that the external bisectors of angles AHB , BHC , CHA meet $AB,BC,CA$ respectively at three collinear points.

**What I Tried**:- Here is a picture :-

[image]

I first concluded that to show the required thing, I need to show, from the Converse of Menelaus Theorem, that :-

$$\rightarrow \frac{AY}{YC} * \frac{CX}{XB} * \frac{BZ}{ZA} = -1$$

But then, I cannot proceed. I tried Ceva's Theorem to get some more information but in this case it did not work like I expected.

Can someone help me solve this?

Thank You.

Comment: @Blue You are perfectly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply external angle bisector theorem in $\triangle AHB, \triangle AHC$ and $\triangle BHC$. So we have,

$\frac{AZ}{BZ} = \frac{AH}{BH} \ \ ...(i)$

$\frac{CY}{AY} = \frac{CH}{AH} \ \ ...(ii)$

$\frac{CX}{BX} = \frac{CH}{BH} \implies \frac{BX}{CX} = \frac{BH}{CH} \ \ ...(iii)$

Multiplying both LHS and RHS of $(i), (ii)$ and $(iii)$, we get

$ \frac{BX}{XC}  \cdot \frac{CY}{YA} \cdot \frac{AZ}{ZB} = 1$

Can you conclude?

Comment: I got it, thanks. Rest follows from Converse of Menelaus Theorem.

Comment: Yes that is correct.